# Prove/Disprove: The set linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ such that $T^n = 0$ and let $A$ be the matrix representing $T$.
>   Prove or Disprove: $\{I,A+I,(A+I)^2,...,(A+I)^n \}$ is linearly dependent.

For the most questions I have a lead. I really struggling find one for this question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set is in fact linearly dependent.

Note that all the powers of $A$ are in the span of the given set. For example:
$$A=(A+I) - I$$ and $$A^2= (A+I)^2 - 2A -I$$ and so on up to the power $n-1$.

Now with the binomial formula we get:

$$(A+I)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} A^k$$

which is a linear combination of the first $n-1$ powers of $A$ since $A^n=0$. Hence it lies in the span of the set $\{I, A+I, (A+I)^2, \ldots, (A+I)^{n-1}\}$.

Comment: Great! One little thing:  
We know that $T^n = 0$. Why is it implying that $A^n = 0$?

Comment: Because $A^n$ is the matrix representing $T^n=0$ which is the zero-homomorphism (so $A^n$ itself has to be the zero-matrix).